# No Eclipse in Open With menu

Tags: eclipse

I want to open all the .java files with Eclipse to edit instead of gedit. I tried the open with menu but eclipse isn't listed there. How to I get this done? I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 edition. I have not installed Eclipse using apt-get but have downloaded eclipse as a part of ADT-BUNDLE (Tools for Android Development).

I would like to a general method to select other program for running a file that is not listed in Other Applications as there is an option in Windows for browse to any other program.

Comment: Do you have Eclipse installed using `apt-get` or you downloaded the package from the webpage?

Comment: @LeopoldoPla I edited the post so that it's visible to all

Answer (score 1):

In terminal write:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Then paste and modify this text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Configurable and extensible IDE
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse %F
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Development;IDE;GTK;
StartupNotify=true
```

Save and close the file. If needed modify `Exec` and `Icon` paths, according to where you have Eclipse executable and its icon. I have it in `/opt/eclipse`. You need to leave `%F` after `exec` path.

After it's done, right-click desired file and choose `open with` (or something similar). Find eclipse and it's done.

More details: [Add Program to List of Applications in “Open With” When Right-Clicking Files in Nautilus](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/).